# The existence of a valued field whose valuation group is ${Q}^2$

Tags: group-theory, valuation-theory

I need to prove that there is a valued field whose valuation group is $Q^2$.
I know that the valuation group of $k((t^{1/n}))$ is $\frac{Z}{n}$ then if we take the union of $k((t^{1/n}))$ we get ${k((t))}_{pui}$ which has $Q$ as a valuation group.
so in order to get a valuation group ${Q}^2$ can I look at ${k((t,s))}_{pui}$?

Answer (score 2):

Construct a valuation on $k[x,y]$ with value group $\Bbb{Z}^2$ with the lexical order.

This valuation extends naturally to $\bigcup_{n\ge 1} k[x^{1/n},y^{1/n}]$ (with value group $\Bbb{Q}^2$ with lexical order) and to its fraction field.

Comment: Thank you. But is my answer incorrect?

Comment: Yes because it takes 1 line to define the valuation! Unclear what you mean with $k((t,s))$ or its Puiseux series.

Comment: okay thank you.

Comment: The field you'd probably want to consider first is $k((t))((s))$ (Laurent series in $s$ whose coefficients are Laurent series in $t$), note that it is not the fraction field of $k[[t,s]]$. and then $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}k((t^{1/n}))((s^{1/n}))$

Comment: yes that's what I wanted to say I guess. sorry